# I'm not sure how to refer to the weights in this Neural Network Train method

Tags: c++, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm writing my **own** implementation of a *Neural Network* class in C++. I'm not sure how to refer to the weights this statement:

```cpp
in = in + (inputs [l] * calcWeights [l]) ;
```

The reason is because there could be **more** weights than inputs. Here is my code:

```cpp
void Train (int numInputs, int numOutputs, double inputs [], double outputs []) {
    // Set the Random Seed:
    srand (time (0)) ;

    // Weights (n input(s) * n output(s) = n weight branch(es)):
    double calcWeights [numInputs * numOutputs] ;

    // Errors (n input(s) * n output(s) = n error branch(es)):
    double errors [numInputs * numOutputs] ;

    // Set the Weights to random:
    for (int j = 0 ; j < numInputs ; j = j + 1) {
        calcWeights [j] = ((-1 * numInputs) + (((double) rand ()) % (1 * numInputs))) ;
    }

    // Train:
    int i = 0 ;
    double in = 0 ;
    double out [numOutputs] ;
    while (i < 14999) {
        // Get the estimated output:
        for (int k = 0 ; k < numOutputs ; k = k + 1) {
            for (int l = 0 ; l < numInputs ; l = l + 1) {
                in = in + (inputs [l] * calcWeights [l]) ;
            }

            out [k] = in + GetBias () ;
        }

        for (int m = 0 ; m < numOutputs ; m = m + 1) {
            error [m] = outputs [m] - out [m]
        }

        // Increment the iterator:
        i = i + 1 ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not entirely clear what you're asking. What about `calcWeights[l + k*numInputs]`. You're only initializing some of your weights.

Comment: @super I've taken each weight as a connection and each Neural Network contains multiple Neurons that accept inputs and outputs. The connection between these Neurons are the weights. The equation I'm using is `input1 * weight1 + ... + inputN * weightN + bias = output`. So, I meant: **how can I multiply each weight and input value together without leaving any weight left alone?**

Comment: I still don't get it. Could you include a small example of what you expect the code to do if there are for example 2 inputs and 2 outputs. You then have 4 weights, correct? So which weight is used is dependent on both the current input and output, no? So you want `i1 * w1 + i2 * w2 + b = o1` and `i1 * w3 + i2 * w4 + b = o2`.

Comment: @super If I give it two inputs and I expect two outputs, the equations will be `(i1 * w1) + (i2 * w2) + b = o1` and `(i1 * w3) + (i2 + w4) + b = o2`. If I give it 3 inputs and I expected 2 outputs,  the equations would be `(i1 * w1) + (i2 * w2) + (i3 * w3) + b = o1` and `(i1 * w4) + (i2 * w5) + (i3 * w6) + b = o2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your clarification in comments, I believe modifying your loop a bit will give you what you want.

```
for (int k = 0 ; k < numOutputs ; k = k + 1) {
    in = 0; //Reset in to 0 at the beginning of each output loop

    for (int l = 0 ; l < numInputs ; l = l + 1) {
        in = in + (inputs [l] * calcWeights [l + k*numInputs]) ;
    }

    out [k] = in + GetBias () ;
}
```

You should also make sure you initialize all the weights above.

```
for (int j = 0 ; j < (numInputs * numOutputs) ; j = j + 1) {
    calcWeights [j] = ((-1 * numInputs) + (((double) rand ()) % (1 * numInputs))) ;
}
```

For a couple of style choices I just want to point out that you can replace `k = k + 1` with simply `++k`. Likewise you can replace `in = in + ...;` with `in += ...;`

Comment: If my weights are calculated in the form that you showed me above, must my error array also be calculated in the same way? If not, please may you explain... Thanks.

Comment: That would depend on what error function you are using. Have a look [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/artificial-neural-network/#training-the-model).

Comment: I have made the Error correct by using the same `for` loop style. Thanks.